Dates Excel Formula
I want to create a formula to return True if the dates on a row are in increasing or equal chronological order.
That bit is straight forward enough but the issue is, if the preceding cell is N/A the date will be blank and needs to be excluded from the sequence

=IF(AND(OR(B1<=C1, B1="N/A", C1="N/A", C1=""), OR(C1<=D1, D1="N/A", D1="")), TRUE, FALSE)


Hey, what's the version of Excel you're using?

Also, could you please post showing the column headers? How many rows need to be processed? From the screenshot it looks like the cells could be Yes, No, N/A, blank or a date, right?
